# Semi-supervised outlier detection data preparation

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-mining, weka

I am trying to write semi-supervised outlier detection algorithm in data stream. I have a training data set which has normal and abnormal behavior of a system. My task is to detect the outliers in the stream of data produced by the system. For the purpose of simulating the data stream, I divided the data into batches.

```
 B1(990,-), B2(106,-), B3(101,5), B4(106,-), B5(101,5) 
 % where Batch_number(#normal, #abnormal)
```

The `B1` represent the training data (which includes normal data records only), while  `B2,B3,B4,B5` are the testing batches. In `B3` and `B5` there are abnormal data records. The normal data in the `B3-B5` is taken from `B1`. My question is , for the semi-supervised learning, does that make a sense? and is it correct to take normal data from the `B1`?

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried?

Comment: To avoid **overfitting** you must also test with normal data that was *not* part of your training set. Make sure that you evaluation method corrects for the imbalancedness. Otherwise, you will get 99% correct with a "there are no anomalies" result. Test this, too: a classifier that just always says "normal". If you can't clearly outperform this, you lost.